# Static Site on Netlify, block spam bots

Tags: gatsby, spam-prevention, netlify

I have two websites built with GatsbyJS hosted on Netlify that are receiving some hits from spambots.

I'm not sure how I would be able to do that, there's no .htaccess for netlify and their _redirects does not cover this kind of scenario.

I would image I need to use a lambda function to intercept the URL the user comes from and perform something, in this case, send them back to where they came from.

Anybody already went through this issue and has a quick solution?

Comment: probably you need to setup a reverse proxy in front of netlify server to filter out the spam requests